# ofstream, duplicated values

Tags: c++, char

values on the output are duplicated

CODE:

```
enum class status_t
    {
        _success,
    };

    const char* set_status(status_t status)
    {
       switch(status)
       {
       case status_t::_success: return xorstr_("[SUCCESS]");
       }
    }

    enum class action_t
    {
        _launch,
    };

    const char* set_action(action_t action)
    {
       switch (action)
       {
       case action_t::_launch: return xorstr_("[LAUNCH]");
       }
    
    }

    void record(const char* status, const char* action, char* message)
    {
       const char* directory = "C:\\log.txt";
       std::ofstream out(directory, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);
       out << status << char(0x20) << action << char(0x20) << message << '\n';
       out.close();
    }

    int main()
    {
      record(set_status(status_t::_success), set_action(action_t::_launch), "success");
    }
```

output: [SUCCESS] [SUCCESS] success

what can cause such an unusual problem?
I do not know what stackoverflow wants me to write here, enough to understand the problem

Comment: I think you tagged wrong language.

Comment: First two strings appear to be returned by `xorstr_` which is not part of the posted code.

Comment: @dxiv xorstr - a heavily vectorized c++17 compile time string encryption. sleepy didn't notice that the code was sent along with xorstr_. without xorstr_, the output is the same.

Comment: @MFR Not so. Without `xorstr_` [the output is](https://godbolt.org/z/cs3Wzd) `[SUCCESS] [LAUNCH] success`. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you specifically interested in the character whose encoding is 32 in some character encoding, or do you want blankspace in the default encoding? The latter is spelled `' '`.